# WebAPI - регистр символов в JSON ответе

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, json.net

1) Есть WebAPI метод, который возвращает объект класса `User`. Все поля этого объекта на стороне клиента приходят с заглавной буквы. Мне нужно, чтобы приходил camelCase. Прописывать у каждого поля `[PropertyName]` не хочется, но `ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();` почему-то не работает. Как это сделать?
2) В классе `UserList` (см.код ниже) есть ссылка на User. При попытке вернуть `UserList` или `User` падает ошибка о self referencing loop. Но в конфиге прописано 
`config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;`, почему не отрабатывает? Опять же, руками указывать `[JsonIgnore]` вариант не нравится.

В WebApiConfig прописано:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        ...

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.Objects;
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore; 
    }
}
```

Объект из контроллера возвращаю следующий образом:

```
var user = Data.GetUserByUserName(userName);

return Json<object>(new
        {
            success = true,
            user = user
        });
```

Класс User

```
public class User : BaseEntity
{
    public string Login { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public List<UserList> UserLists { get; set; }

    public string AvatarFileID { get; set; }
    public int? AvatarFileProviderID { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для корректной работы нужно возвращать не `Json<object>`, а просто `object`. Например, таким образом:

```
return new
{
    success = true,
    user = user
};
```